# Moq returning an Action from a void method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method that returns a long number to an lambda which is used after as shown below.

```
classA.GetNum((num) =>
        {
            numTwo = num;
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                NumberIs = num;
            });
        });
```

and I'm trying to Moq the return from the action here ;

```
void GetNum(Action<long> num);
```

I've tried this so far, but wasn't successful and haven't been able to find any other ways online of moqing a simple action like this.

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetNum(It.IsAny<Action<long>>()))
            .Callback(() => 255);
```

Comment: Already looked at that, it's similar to mine. I've literally been through every stack overflow and googlable concoction of the subject I can find.

Comment: Apologise, found the answer, been a long day of writing tests, I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comment from that post; I simply needed to add the below for it to work.

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetNum(It.IsAny<Action<long>>()))
        .Callback((Action<long> cb) => cb(255));
```

Sorry for the duplicate!